# Inverses -- Whether it is necessary to prove $AB=BA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

To prove that $B$ is the inverse of $A$, I recall from some other classes that it is necessary to show both $AB = BA$ and $AB = I$.

Yesterday, in my algebra class, I was totally stunned by my teacher as she said that it is not necessary to prove $AB=BA$ at all with the following proof:

Suppose $$AB = I$$

$$\det (AB) = \det I = 1$$

$$\det A \cdot \det B= 1$$

$$\det A \neq 0 \text{ and } \det B \neq 0$$

$\implies A^{-1}$ exists.

Multiplying $A^{-1}$ from LHS on both sides,

$$A^{-1} \cdot A \cdot B = A^{-1} \cdot I$$

$$B = A^{-1}.$$

Therefore for any $AB = I$, $B$ is the inverse of $A$.

> What is wrong with this proof?

Comment: Whenever $A$ and $B$ both are square matrices. $AB=I$ is enough to conclude that $B$ is the inverse of $A$. But $AB =I$ may happen with $A$ or $B$ not square matrices.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: In any group (not necessary commutative), it can be proven that $ab=e$ implies $ba=e$ . But here, since we know that $\det(A)\ne 0$ already ensures that $A$ is invertible, your proof shows in an easy way that $B$ is actually the inverse, so we do not need that fact. However, the proof is correct, as long as the matrices are both square matrices.

Comment: sorry im new i really don't know how to use mathsjax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong in the proof, since it is not necessary to prove $AB=BA$

Because $$AB=I \implies AB=BA$$

Let's see how,

Since $$AB=I \implies \det(A) \cdot \det (B) =\det (I)=1$$

$\implies \det(B) \neq 0 \implies $ $B$ has an inverse.

$$AB = I \implies BAB=B$$
(Pre-multiplying by $B$)

$BAB=B \implies BABB^{-1}=BB^{-1}=I $$
(Post-multiplying by $B^{-1}$)

$$BA=I=AB$$

Comment: The result is ultimately true, but you did not prove that $B$ has right inverse. You just assumed it, which is more of the same.

Answer (score 1):

The proof assumes that you already know that every square matrix $A$ with nonzero determinant *has* an inverse $A^{-1}$ that works from both sides.

Once you know this general fact, you can use the proof you quote to conclude that the $B$ you're looking at is in fact that inverse if only $AB=I$.

You would need more than this if you wanted to show general facts about inverses from first principles, but this is a perfectly good reasoning when you have particular matrices $A$ and $B$ that you're interested in.

Comment: (Actually for this particular argument we only need to know in advance that $A^{-1}$ is a _left_ inverse, but if instead you know $BA=I$ you would need to repeat the entire argument in mirror image, using that $A^{-1}$ is a right inverse).

Answer (score 1):

In general, if we have an element $A$ of an unitary ring, then the fact that there is an element $B$ such that $AB=1$ doesn't imply that $BA=1$.

However, in this specific situation (square matrices) these assertions are equivalent, given a matrix $A$:

1. there is a matrix $B$ such that $BA=\operatorname{Id}$;
2. there is a matrix $B$ such that $AB=\operatorname{Id}$;
3. $\det A\neq0$

and when they hold, the matrices $B$ from the first and the second assertions are unique and are the same.